# How to heat up two bowls in a microwave?

Tags: kitchen

Some of us use microwave's for just one bowl. But I want to know if there's a life hack to add two bowls into a microwave at the same time? This would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Should do the trick. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best ones.

Image from Google Images / Reddit

Comment: Worked perfect!!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a non-metallic rack to place the other bowl on top of the first one.

Do also note that heating two bowls, will take a little more than double the time of heating the one bowl, so it might not be worth the trouble. (Similar to heating the double amount, is a little more than the time used for the original amount)

Regarding what to use as a rack, which is readily available in a home, it depends on size of bowls and size of microwave:

- Ideally, you buy a specific rack made for the purpose
- Some microwave ovens comes with a lid to use over the food. This can, if you don't obstruct the air flow, be used as the rack
- You could try balancing the other bowl on top of the other using chop sticks layed parallell on top of the first bowl
- You could use skewer sticks stuck through plastic glasses, or somehow interconnected to build a proper frame/rack
- I've also seen a triple bowl arrangement used, where the first bowl is placed of center, the second empty bowl is turned upside down and placed next to the first bowl, and then the third bowl is placed on top of the second bowl and possibly the rim of the first bowl
- Similar to the previous where you have your first bowl placed of center, and then something which fits your rotating plate and has the same height as your bowl placed next to it, and then finally the second bowl placed on top of the non-metallic height adjustment thingy and the rim of the other bowl

All these suggestions are based on bowls, where the content is below the rim of the bowl. As such, it can't be easily done with plates. With plates you need do get/build/... the rack so that the food doesn't touch the other plate.

Comment: That's basically the answer I was going to give, Holroy. :) On top of the bottom bowl you can also place a plate, and place the other bowl on top of that. It will restrict airflow, which might be an issue. I have also used a plastic "splatter cover": place that over the first bowl as though to prevent splattering, then place the second bowl on top of the splatter cover.